# Ускорение парсера animebuff

Tags: python, asyncio, xpath, aiohttp, lxml

Я сейчас работаю над асинхронным парсером для animebuff, но столкнулся с проблемой скорости сбора данных парсера(это может затянуться до нескольких минут от 15 до 20 вроде, а может и больше). Хотел спросить как мне его ускорить?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time
from lxml import  html

async def getMaxPages(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        doc = html.fromstring(await resp.text())
        return int(doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/ul/li[last()-1]/a/text()")[0])

async def getHtml(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        print("Обрабатываю: ", url)
        return await resp.text()

async def getLinks(session, url):
    pages = await getHtml(session=session, url=url)
    doc = html.fromstring(pages)
    links = doc.xpath("//a[@class='anime-item']/@href")

    allLinks = []
    for link in links:
        fullLink = "https://animebuff.ru" + str(link)
        allLinks.append(fullLink)
    return allLinks

async def getData(session,  url):
    links = await getLinks(session=session, url=url)
    for link in links:
        data = await getHtml(session=session, url=link)
        doc = html.fromstring(data)

        title = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/text()")
        eps = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()")
        year = doc.xpath("//div[@class='anime__info-value']/a[contains(string(), '1') or contains(string(), '2') or contains(string(), '3') or contains(string(), '4') or contains(string(), '5') or contains(string(), '6') or contains(string(), '7') or contains(string(), '8') or contains(string(), '9') or contains(string(), '0')]/text()")
        rating = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/text()")
        lenOfEps = doc.xpath("//div[@class='anime__info-item']/div[contains(string(), 'мин')]/text()")
        descr = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/p/text()")
        img = doc.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/img/@src")

        res = []
        if title and eps and year and rating and lenOfEps and descr and img:
            for AnimeTitle, AnimeYear, AnimeEps, AnimeRating, AnimeLenOfEps, AnimeDescr, AnimeImg in zip(title, year, eps, rating, lenOfEps, descr, img):
                res.append({
                "Title": AnimeTitle,
                "Year": AnimeYear,
                "Epizodes": AnimeEps,
                "Rating": AnimeRating,
                "LenOfEpizodes": AnimeLenOfEps,
                "Description": AnimeDescr,
                "Image": "https://animebuff.ru" + AnimeImg,
                "Link": link
                })
        if res:
            print(res)



async def main():
    startT = time.time()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        maxPages = await getMaxPages(session, "https://animebuff.ru/anime")
        tasks = []
        for page in range(1, maxPages):
            url = f"https://animebuff.ru/anime?page={page}"
            tasks.append(getData(session=session, url=url))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    print(time.time() - startT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Завершение программы!")
```

Comment: Во-первых, выполните профилирование вашего кода, определите узкие участки. Во-вторых, попробуйте использовать для парсинга библиотеку selectolax.